# how can i add checkbox in a column header? ext js

Tags: extjs, header, checkbox, grid

I have a grid, with dynamically changing number of columns. I've already got column with checkboxes. I need to add a checkBox to other columns headers, only to headers.

Comment: why are you adding checkbox to column header? can you explain the functionality you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Maybe he wants a select or unselect all functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Include the `Ext.grid.CheckboxSelectionModel` as a column when declaring your ColumnModel.

```
var colModel = new Ext.grid.ColumnModel({
    columns: [ new Ext.grid.CheckboxSelectionModel(),
    {/* other columns}]
});
```